# Trying to use HttpClient class in Azure

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a simple Azure Function that checks whether a given URL is available (this is just a proof-of-concept).  My problem is I can't figure out which library I need to import to get thr client class.  The Azure docs are not at all clear, and all examples are C# or .NET

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    target = req.params.get('target')
    if not target:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            target = req_body.get('target')

    if target:
        try:
            MyClient = HttpClient()
            response = MyClient.GetAsync(f"http://{target}")
        except:
                return func.HttpResponse("Error", status_code = 500)
        if response.StatusCode == 200 or response.StatusCode == 302:
            return func.HttpResponse("OK")
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("Bad", status_code = 503)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "No target specified",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Requirements.txt:

```
azure-functions==1.2.1
altgraph==0.17
future==0.18.2
pefile==2019.4.18
PyInstaller==3.6
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can install `requests` in your python function by running the below command in "Terminal" window of VS code.

```
pip install requests
```

And then import it and use it as below (just check the `status_code` of `response`):

[image]

**Update:**

According to some test, I reproduced your problem. It seems you didn't install the `requests` module success on azure, you just install it in your function in local. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** I assume you have installed the `requests` module in local and run the function success in local(if still have problem, please let me know). Then please run the below command in "Terminal" window in VS code to generate the "requirements.txt".

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image]

The "requirements.txt" is used to install modules, when you deploy the function to azure, azure will install the modules according to the content in "requirements.txt". After running the command above to generate the "requirements.txt", you can see it show like this:
[image]

The reason for your function showed 500 error(with "this page isn't working") is missing "requests" in "requirements.txt".

**2.** Then run the command in "Terminal" window to deploy the function from local to azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName> --build remote
```

The `<functionAppName>` is the name of the function app(python) you created on azure portal.

**3.** After that, go to azure portal to test your function, it will work fine.

Comment: Hi @RonTrunk I test the code both on local and on azure, it works. So, may I know what do you mean that "this does not work with Azure" ? How did you deploy it from local to azure (with the modules installed in the function on azure) ?

Comment: I used visualstudio to deploy it.  When I run the function, it returns "this page isn't working" and 500 error.

Comment: @RonTrunk I've never run python function in visual studio, I always run python function in VS code. I think this is also the way(which recommended by azure) to develop python function and deploy to azure. And most of the document are about develop and deploy python in VS code, I think you can consider change to VS code to develop your python.

Comment: Hi @RonTrunk I reproduced your issue, please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I updated the requirements.txt file as you suggested (see updated question, but still doesn't work.  If I run the app without a target, I get the "no target specified" error as expected.  but if I specify a target (real or fake), I get the 500 error "this page isn't working.

Comment: If the target is a invalid URL, I get the proper response.  but if the target is a real site, then I get the "page isn't working" error.

Comment: Hi @RonTrunk I test it in my side, it works fine. I guess you made some mistake with the "status" in your code. When request the url by `requests` module, we need to use `response.status_code` but not `response.StatusCode` which provided in your code. Here I provide a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WXYY.png) of my code for your reference.

Comment: I think I was also trying this on Azure, and copied part of the syntax from that.  Anyway, thank you very much for your help.  It works now.